# PHP undefined index

Tags: php

Heya I get this error message. I've been looking everywhere but I dont know how to fix it? Im a beginner so I'm really confued. Thanks in advance

Notice: Undefined index: cart in /nas/students/j/j39-green/unix/public_html/ISD5/inc/functions.inc.php on line 3

You have no items in your shopping cart

```
<?php
function writeShoppingCart() {
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
if (!$cart) {
    return '<p>You have no items in your shopping cart</p>';
} else {
    // Parse the cart session variable
    $items = explode(',',$cart);
    $s = (count($items) > 1) ? 's':'';
    return '<p>You have <a href="cart.php">'.count($items).' item'.$s.'  in your shopping cart</a></p>';
}
}
```

Comment: The error is in functions.Inc.php not your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$_SESSION['cart']` isn't set, it throws that warning.

Try:

```
$cart = isset($_SESSION['cart'])?$_SESSION['cart']:false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "EMPTY":

```
<?php
function writeShoppingCart() {
    $cart = !empty($_SESSION['cart']);
    if (!$cart) {
        return '<p>You have no items in your shopping cart</p>';
    } else {
        // Parse the cart session variable
        $items = explode(',',$cart);
        $s = (count($items) > 1) ? 's':'';
        return '<p>You have <a href="cart.php">'.count($items).' item'.$s.'  in your       shopping cart</a></p>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that the key 'cart' does not exist in the $_SESSION superglobal array.

If it's alright for this value to not exist, you should be doing this:

```
$cart = false;
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
}
```

You could use something called the ternary operator, in PHP, but since you're a beginner, I don't want to bombard you.

In development mode, it's alright to display errors but you should read more about disabling errors (error_reporting) and logging them (error_log()) so that they can be inspected without alarming visitors.

Answer (score 0):

That means that your session does not contain `$_SESSION['cart']`

Try this instead:

```
$cart = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$cart = isset($_SESSION['cart']) ? $_SESSION['cart'] : NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

try initializing your $_SESSION with something like:

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = 0;    // zero items in cart
```